# How to automatically log on to asp.net application

Tags: c#, web-applications

I am building an intranet application, the requirement is to log in user without asking for credentials with the windows credentials he has logged on to computer, user if wants can logout from application and log in using the windows credentials pop up.

Comment: you couldve simply googled this bro! I felt like downvoting but I dont downvote people.

Answer (score 2):

[Use Windows Authentication.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998358.aspx)

Though, I don't think there's really a way to sign out of a website using Windows authentication. You're either authenticated or you aren't.

Also, I believe the automatic logging in will only occur:

- When using IE
- After saving credentials after logging in the first time in other browsers
- After editing browser-specific settings (like [FireFox's NTLM setting](http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/))